# Append record APDU get an error response of 69, 86 even if there is an EF file that exists

Tags: smartcard, apdu

The APDU UPDATE RECORD gives me an error of SW=1 69 SW2= 86 : Command not allowed (no current EF)

```
APDU: CLA = 0x00 , INS = 0xE2, P1 = 0x00 , p2 = 0x00 , len = length of data  , data
```

I select the EF file before executing the code with a result of:
`sw1=90 sw2=00` so therefore it exists.

I also tried to run Create EF file and it gives me an error of:

```
sw1 = 6A sw2=89 : File Already Exists.
```

I run also get challenge and external authenticate prior to the update record but the issue still remains.

are there any other things I must consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error *69 86* does not mean, that the file does not exist, but that currently no EF whatsoever is selected, on which the APPEND RECORD could operate. My best guess is, that between your selection (proving existence of the EF) and the attempt to append to it somehing happens, which spoils the selection, e. g. selection of the DF containing the authentication key, or selection of the EF containing the key if your smart card OS stores them that way.

Only suggestion: try to reselect the EF directly before the append or use P2 to specify a short EF identifier if you are still in the correct DF at least.